# Cosa significa la frase "come mai"?

Tags: meaning, idioms

Vorrei chiedere che cosa significa la frase "come mai". Mi pare  un'espressione idiomatica interessante. L'ho incontrata una volta con un oggetto (città), come per esempio: "Come mai a Venezia?". Come si dice questo essattamente? Grazie.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: ciao Charo, Grazie.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

L'espressione **"Come mai"** ha in pratica lo stesso significato di **"Perché"**, serve per introdurre una domanda, e si utilizza soprattutto nella lingua parlata per esprimere un senso di stupore oppure che accade un fatto che si discosta dalla nostra esperienza, come viene spiegato [qui](https://www.italki.com/question/92429?hl=it).

Nella frase indicata *"Come mai a Venezia?"* è sottointeso il verbo, che potrebbe essere:

> Come mai (ti trovi) a Venezia?

Ma potrebbe essere anche:

> Come mai (vuoi andare) a Venezia?

In entrambi i casi chi pone la domanda utilizza "come mai" per sottolineare il suo stupore o un'incongruenza con la propria esperienza.

Sempre nella stessa pagina, viene indicato che questa espressione potrebbe essere una forma contratta di:

> come (è) mai (possibile che)...

Si potrebbe utilizzare in sostituzione: **"Per quale motivo..."** che però è più formale.

Secondo me l'equivalente inglese potrebbe essere *"How it comes that..."* oppure *"How it is possible that..."*

Comment: Grazie molto Riccardo, penso che fosse meglio `"Quando si dice "perché" e quando "come mai"?"` sia meglio per la mia domanda come suo collegamento che offre.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: Il tuo commento non è chiarissimo; ricorda che puoi scrivere anche in inglese, se ti è più comodo.

Comment: @DaG ok, grazie :) I meant that I'd better asking my question as `"Quando si dice "perché" e quando "come mai"?"` like Riccardo's link suggested ( I explain my thanksgiving to him, also for this reason  ).

Comment: Grazie a te, @BarbarosÖzhan.

Comment: Aggiungo alla risposta di Riccardo che – anche se “come mai” è un'espressione fissa – più in generale “mai” si può aggiungere anche ad altri tipi di interrogazioni per rafforzarle ed esprimere quasi un senso di incredulità: “chi mai lo crederebbe?” (vedi [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mai), punto 3).

Answer (score 4):

Come dice il Dizionario De Mauro (https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/come-mai), «come mai» è una locuzione avverbiale che significa "perché?", "per quale ragione?".

Si usa nelle domande e nelle interrogative indirette, ma non nelle risposte.

Comment: grazie mille Benedetta.